# sql and java querying data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have two tables, one contains college name and college id while another contains year wise enrollment of students in different colleges.

What I want is to print the number of students enrolled in a year for different colleges and total number of students enrolled every year.

Currently what I'm doing is getting college id from first table and then running a for loop for year and counting the number of students.

What is happening with this is inside for loop every time a new `PreparedStatement` is being created, which I feel is little expensive.

Is there a better way of running a SQL query to get the required data.

My code that is being currently used is below

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select id from college where type_flag = '1' order by full_form");

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {


    for (int i = 1964; i < 2019; i++) {
        String pstmt11 = "select count(*) from students where id=" + rs.getInt("id") + "AND year = " + i;
        //System.out.println(pstmt11);
        PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(pstmt11);
        //pstmt1.setInt(1, rs.getInt("case_type"));
        ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();

        while (rs1.next()) {
            //Here I am getting the count

        }
```

Similarly for getting year wise count I am doing the same thing.

Comment: `year BETWEEN 1964 AND 2019`

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of a `PreparedStatement` is not really using a prepared statement. You should only prepare it *once* with placeholders for the values then use `setInt()` to pass the values.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select id from college where type_flag = '1' order by full_form");
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from students where id=? and year=?");

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {

    for (int i = 1964; i < 2019; i++) {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        pstmt1.setInt(1, id);
        pstmt2.setInt(2, i);
        ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
        while (rs1.next()) {
            //Here I am getting the count
        }
    }
}
```

You should also use a placeholder for the first statement.

---

There is however no need for a loop or two statements. What you want can be done with a single query:

```
select id, year, count(*)
from students
where id in (select id 
             from college
             where type_flag = '1')
and year between 1964 and 2018
group by id, year;
```

---

I am surprised that `college.id` equals the `id` column in the `students` table. From a naming perspective I would have expected a `students.college_id` column, and `students.id` being the primary key of the `students` table identifying the student, not the college.

Comment: Given the original code, your query should probably use `select id, year, count()` and `group by id, year` (at least to answer the _"number of students enrolled in a year for different colleges"_, the current query answers _"total number of students enrolled every year"_).

Comment: @ I had tried using the query suggested by you bt i was only using group by year but it was only returning 71 rows..can you suggest as what goes wrong when i use only group by year...secondly the id column in student table does refer to id column in college table

Comment: @vidhu: you should ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that - providing sample data and the expected results.

Comment: @vidhu You need to start accepting answers. There is a green tick, hit it.